# I have a error because install react-native into my app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, package

I installed react native into my app. And now I can't start my app.

I show you code from a package.json, my code from component and error code. I tried to install react-native from npm but now I past something from react-native-app.

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
"apollo-cache-inmemory": "^1.1.10",
"apollo-client": "^2.2.6",
"apollo-link-http": "^1.5.3",
"babel-polyfill": "^7.0.0-beta.2",
"bluebird": "^3.5.1",
"body-parser": "^1.18.2",
"bunyan": "^1.8.12",
"cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
"core-js": "^2.5.1",
"express": "^4.16.1",
"express-jwt": "^5.3.0",
"graphql": "^0.11.7",
"graphql-tag": "^2.5.0",
"history": "^4.7.2",
"htmlparser2": "^3.9.2",
"isomorphic-style-loader": "^4.0.0",
"json2csv-stream": "^0.1.4",
"jsonwebtoken": "^8.0.1",
"libphonenumber-js": "^0.4.38",
"moment": "^2.20.1",
"morgan": "^1.9.0",
"node-fetch": "^1.7.3",
"normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
"pretty-error": "^2.1.1",
"prop-types": "^15.6.0",
"query-string": "^5.0.0",
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.57.8",
"react-apollo": "^2.0.4",
"react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
"react-collapsible": "^2.0.3",
"react-dom": "^16.0.0",
"react-google-maps": "^9.4.5",
"react-loadable": "^5.5.0",
"react-scroll": "^1.5.5",
"react-scrollbar": "^0.5.4",
"react-textarea-autosize": "^5.2.1",
"serialize-javascript": "^1.3.0",
"source-map-support": "^0.5.0",
"universal-router": "^4.2.0",
"whatwg-fetch": "^2.0.3"
 },
   "devDependencies": {
"assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
"autoprefixer": "^7.1.4",
...(babel)
"browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
"metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
"chokidar": "^1.7.0",
"css-loader": "^0.28.7",
"enzyme": "^3.1.0",
"eslint": "^4.8.0",
"eslint-config-airbnb": "^15.1.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^2.6.0",
"eslint-import-resolver-node": "^0.3.1",
"eslint-loader": "^1.9.0",
"eslint-plugin-css-modules": "^2.7.5",
"eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.38.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.7.0",
"eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^5.1.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.3.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^7.4.0",
"file-loader": "^1.1.5",
"flow-bin": "^0.56.0",
"front-matter": "^2.2.0",
"glob": "^7.1.2",
"husky": "^0.14.3",
"identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
"jest": "^21.2.1",
"jscodeshift": "^0.3.32",
"lint-staged": "^4.2.3",
"markdown-it": "^8.4.0",
"mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
"null-loader": "^0.1.1",
"pixrem": "^4.0.1",
"pleeease-filters": "^4.0.0",
...(postcss)
"prettier": "^1.7.4",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
"react-deep-force-update": "^2.1.1",
"react-dev-utils": "^4.1.0",
"react-error-overlay": "^2.0.2",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0",
"rimraf": "^2.6.2",
"stylelint": "^8.1.1",
"stylelint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
"stylelint-order": "^0.7.0",
"svg-url-loader": "^2.2.0",
"url-loader": "^0.6.2",
"webpack": "^3.6.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.0",
"webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.12.0",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.19.1",
"webpack-node-externals": "^1.6.0"
},
```

code from component:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const deviceWidth = Number(Dimensions.get('window').width - 'px');
 render() { ...
     const slidesStyles =
  deviceWidth >= 800
    ? {
        width: `${100 * children.length / 3}%`,
        transform: `translateX(${-1 *
          index *
          (100 / children.length / 3)}%)`,
      }
    : {
        width: `${100 * children.length}%`,
        transform: `translateX(${-1 * index * (100 / children.length)}%)`,
      }; ...}
```

and error code (it's too big, but all errors link with it):

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native/Libraries/react-native/react-native-implementation.js
```

Can you help me to start my app?

Answer (score 0):

The issue looks like with node_modules folder. Try to delete your node_modules folder using command `rm -rf node_modules` and then run `npm install` and then run your app using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`